# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. c# remoting

Tags: c#, remoting

In our windows application,  we have decorated EntityExtendedDataSet class with Serializable. this class is in DS project.

```
[Serializable()]
    public class EntityExtendedDataSet : EntityDataSet 
    {  }
```

In Business project, we are passing EntityExtendedDataSet object as a parameter in below function

```
public static void SaveEntity(ref EntityExtendedDataSet savedEntity)
{
    IEntityAccessor objAccessor = (IEntityAccessor)RemotingHelper.GetObject(typeof(IEntityAccessor));

    objAccessor.SaveEntity(ref savedEntity); //line 2

}
```

I'm getting exception at line 2 saying that "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"
It is not even entering SaveEntity function in EntityAccessor class, which has SaveEntity function.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Line 2" is `IEntityAccessor objAccessor = ... ` ?

Comment: Check the `InnerException` of the `TargetInvocationException`.

Comment: @Fildor: line 2 is objAccessor.SaveEntity(ref savedEntity); //line 2

Comment: @Peter: InnerException is "Request failed."